# In C#, what's a good way for displaying zoomable, pannable video?

Tags: c#, .net, video, directx, directshow

I've been sorting through DirectX, DirectShow, etc. and can't figure out which .NET C# library would be the best.

I'm making an art installation that will feature full screen video. I'd like the user to be able to pan and zoom in and out on the video as it's playing, ideally with no skipping or hiccups. Is there a Microsoft technology that stands out as an obvious choice for this?

Comment: Perhaps Magnifier could work under Win7? (starting lo-tech to hi-tech)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to consider WPF.. It is a lot faster to get started with than Direct3D... It also has an infrastructure designed for glitch free animations, independent from delays from garbage collection and ui thread activity.

In very complex GUI's, WPF can come with some hidden cost, which annoys people, claiming WPF is slow.
But I am confident it will work fine in the scenario you describe.

Comment: The performance can be very slow, but if used by someone who knows what they're doing it can be quite performant in most circumstances.

Comment: @mydogisbox: I wholeheartedly agree. I did not mean to sound negative of WPF. I'll rephrase...

Comment: Done! I think this better conveys the message I was trying to get across.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Use XNA.  It has much deeper support than the old managed directX.  This guy answered your question for you:  http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/